# The measure of the union of 2 sets.

Tags: measure-theory, functions

A measure space $(\mathbb S,\mathcal S,μ)$ is not complete. The system of all its null sets is $\mathcal O$.

Let
$$ S′=\{A∪O:A∈ \mathcal S,O∈ \mathcal O\}.$$
The formula of the function $μ′:\mathcal S′→[0,∞]$ is
$$μ′(A∪O)=μ(A).$$

**Question:**

(a) Show: $μ′(A_1∪O_1)=μ′(A_2∪O_2),$ if $A_1∪O_1=A_2∪O_2.$

**My solution:**

I am given some hints. I need to show that $A=A_1∪O_1=A_2∪O_2$  in two ways, with $A_1,A_2∈ \mathcal S$ and $O_1,O_2∈ \mathcal O$, then $μ(A_1)=μ(A_2)$. Then according to $μ′(A∪O)=μ(A)$ the final fact will follow.

Answer (score 3):

$A_2 \setminus A_1 \subset O_1 $ so $\mu (A_2 \setminus A_1)=0$. Similarly, $\mu (A_1 \setminus A_2)=0$. Now $\mu (A_1)\leq \mu (A_1 \setminus A_2)+\mu (A_2)=\mu(A_2)$ and the reverse inequality is similar.